# How many real solutions does this equation have: $x^{2}-2\sin x+2x=33$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

> How many real solutions does this equation have: $x^{2}-2\sin x+2x=33$

I have created this equation myself, so it's not homework and I hope it's even solvable.. It will be only for practice.

$$x^{2}-2\sin x+2x=33$$

$$x^{2}-2\sin x+2x-33 = 0$$

$$f'(x) = 0$$

$$2x-2\cos x+2 =0$$

$$x = 0$$

Now check if it's maximum or minimum:

$$f''(x) = 2+2\sin x$$

$$f''(0) = 2+2\sin (0) > 0 \Rightarrow minimum$$

Now let's calculate the point of minimum:

$$0^{2}-2\sin (0)+2\cdot 0 -33= -33$$

$\Rightarrow P(0|-33)$

Now let's check if function is monotonic:

$f'(x) = 2x -2\cos x + 2$

For $x>0$ we get $f'(x) > 0$ , so monotonic increasing

For $x<0$ we get $f'(x) < 0$ , so monotonic decreasing

$\Rightarrow$ Function has $2$ real solutions

---

My questions:

- Did I do it correctly?
- If correct, is there something I could have skipped because not very necessary (I'm thinking to skip the calculation of maximum / minimum and just do the monotony)?

Comment: $f''(0) = 2+2\sin (0)=2 > 0 \Rightarrow \text{minimum}$

Comment: Oh right thank you! I'll correct this now.

Comment: Is everything else alright?

Comment: I think you should add, that $f(\pm \infty)\to\infty$ and with $f(0)<0$ there must be at least $2$ solutions. And it's $f(x)\geq (x-2)(x+2)$ and therefore maximal $2$ solutions.

Comment: $f(0)<0$ and the monotony properties **do not** garantee zeros. But for large $x$ the function is positive so that by the intermediate value theorem you have at least two zeroes. With you argument you show that there are exactly two zeroes.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2B1)%5E2%3D2sin+x%2B34

Comment: So what I need to do is:
1. Calculate extremum 2. monotony 3. limes +-infinty 4. conclude ?

Comment: For 1) No need to calculate the minimum here. The condition $f(0)<0$ is sufficient because $f$ is continous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implicitly defining $f(x)=x^2-2\sin x+2x-33$; the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=2x-2\cos x+2=2(1+x-\cos x)
$$
and the second derivative is
$$
f''(x)=1+\sin x
$$
The second derivative is positive except at isolated points, so the function is convex and it can have at most a point of minimum. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)
$$
we know that the function has an absolute minimum. As $f'(0)=0$, the minimum is located at $0$. Now
$$
f(0)=-33<0
$$
so the equation $f(x)=0$ has two solutions.

---

The problem with your solution is that you didn't prove the only solution of $f'(x)=0$ is $x=0$. This follows from convexity, which is the same as saying that $f'$ is an increasing function. You state, without proof, that $f'(x)<0$ for $x<0$, which is easy, but not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

And sometimes visualizations are really helpful.
[image]

Comment: So what I need to do is:
1. Calculate extremum 2. monotony 3. limes +-infinty 4. conclude ?

Comment: @tenepolis Exactly, but be cautious about the oscillations. This function does not cause any trouble since the effect of $\sin x$ is small, but some functions have oscillations near their intersection with the $x$ axis, which makes it difficult for root number calculations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to proceed with an algebraic proof, it could be better to visualize in this way[image: parab_sinx]